# How to break a program if a string is entered in python

Tags: python

So I wrote a program to find the second largest number. The thing is, I want my program to show the second largest number when an enter key is pressed. But I also want my program to show an error when a string is entered. Here is my code:

```
#py program to find second largest number by user

nums = []
while True:
    user = input("Enter a number. To stop press enter")
    nums.append(user)
    if user=="":
        break
    if user==str:
        print("you have to enter a number!")
        break
nums.remove(max(nums))
print("Second largest number is: ", max(nums))
```

I know that 7th line is not good. Thanks for help :)

Comment: At first you are going to need proper indentation in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison `user==str` doesn't do what you want for two reasons:

1. To test if something is a `str`, you'd want to be comparing its **type** to `str`, not the object itself -- e.g. `type(user) == str`, or maybe `isinstance(user, str)`.
2. Testing whether `user` is a `str` is pointless anyway though, because it is *always* a `str`, even if it contains only numeric characters.  What you really want to know is whether or not it is a `str` whose *value* allows it to be converted to an `int` (or maybe a `float`).

The simplest way to do this is to have a line of code that does the `int` conversion inside a `try` block, and catch the `ValueError` to print the error message if the conversion fails.

```
nums = []
while True:
    # indented code is inside the loop
    user = input("Enter a number. To stop press enter")
    if user == "":
        # stop the loop completely on empty input
        break
    try:
        nums.append(int(user))
    except ValueError:
        # print an error if it didn't convert to an int
        print("you have to enter a number!")
# unindented code is after the loop
nums.remove(max(nums))
print("Second largest number is: ", max(nums))
```